# Проверка корректности идентификатора

Tags: строки

Нужно написать две программы

1. Вводится массив слов с файла. Для каждого слова определить, является ли оно корректным именем (первая буква - буква, остальные - буквы, цифры или подчеркивания).
2. Усовершенствовать предыдущую программу, так чтобы она могла распознавать служебные слова (if, for, do, while, switch, const, int, long) и считала их недопустимыми.

Comment: На каком языке хоть надо?

Comment: @MaksymMykytuk, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Нужно на c++

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, вам требуется применить регулярные выражения для решения или о них ничего не сказано??

Comment: В условии ничего не сказано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот приблизительное решение на Java:

Задача 1

```
ArrayList<String> input = //получаем массив из файла
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>(); //сюда попадут правильные имена
for (String s : input) if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0)) output.add(s);
```

Задача 2

```
ArrayList<String> input = //получаем массив из файла
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>(); //сюда попадут правильные имена
for (String s : input) 
    if (Character.isLetter(c.charAt(0)) & !s.contains("if") & !s.contains("for") ... ) output.add(s);
```